# How to refresh tabs content view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm trying to get help on how to refresh tab host content view when I click back on it while I'm on the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can put Content which you want to resume in onresume method.
like..

```
protected void onResume() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        ls.setFocusable(false);
    }
```

or

```
protected void onResume() 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        i1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radioinactive));
        i2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radioinactive));
        i3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radioinactive));
        i4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radioinactive));
        i5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radioinactive));

}
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to refresh the tabhost activity when i press back on it